# Vanishing holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

*I am currently studying complex analysis and one problem of an exercise sheet is as follows:*

Let $U$ be a non-empty connected open set and let $f, g$ be holomorphic functions
on $U$. If $fg \equiv 0$, then either $f \equiv 0$ or $g \equiv 0$.

*Now I am aware that this problem has already been covered, but I want to know if my proof works, as the connectedness- property of $U$ has not been used:*

Assume by contradiction that $f,g \not\equiv 0$ but $fg \equiv 0$. Define $\Omega_f := \{z \in U | f(z) = 0\}$ and $\Omega_g$ analogously. Observe that $U = \Omega_f \cup \Omega_g$*, since $f(z)g(z) = 0 \implies f(z)=0 \lor g(z)=0$. Now if there existed any open non-empty subset of $\Omega_f$ or $\Omega_g$, we would conclude $f \equiv 0$ or $g \equiv 0$ by the identity theorem. Hence such a subset cannot exist. Since we know that $\Omega_f / \partial \Omega_f$ , $\Omega_f / \partial \Omega_f$ are open subsets, it follows that $\Omega_f / \partial \Omega_f$$=$$\Omega_g / \partial \Omega_g = \emptyset$. But this violates *, since U is open and $(\partial \Omega_f \cap U) \cup\ (\partial \Omega_g \cap U)$ certainly is not. ***qed***

*Any help is appreciated!*

Comment: The connectedness of $U$ is (at least) used in the identity theorem.

Comment: By $/$ you mean $\backslash$?